# How to add where clause to ThenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 3 entities:

`Questionnaire.cs`:

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

`Question.cs`:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

and `Answer.cs`:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string TextAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

So I saved the questionnaire with answers but now i want to retrieve filtered questionnaire with questions and its answers. So i wrote linq for that, but it throws me an error, is there anything i do wrong? here is the example:

```
questionnaire = _context.Questionnaires.Include(qn => qn.Questions)
.ThenInclude(question => question.Answers.Where(a => a.UserId == userId))
.FirstOrDefault(qn => qn.Id == questionnaireId);
```

And i am getting

> Message = "The property expression 'q => {from Answer a in q.Answers
>   where Equals([a].UserId, __userId_0) select [a]}' is not valid. The
>   expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: can you tell me what is your query what you want to find ?

Comment: Every questionnaire has questions and questions has answers, and i need to filter these question answers by userId.

Comment: I changed your model class to have a navigation property of Question in your answer . var questionnaire = ctx.Answers.Include(q=>q.Question).Where(a =>a.UserId=="1").ToList();

Answer (score 14):

Filtering in `Include` or `ThenInclude` is not supported. Create projection by using `Select`:

```
questionnaire = _context.Questionnaires
    .Select(n => new Questionnaire
    {
        Id = n.Id,
        Name = n.Name,
        Questions = n.Questions.Select(q => new Question
        {
           Id = q.Id,
           Text = q.Text,
           Answers = q.Where(a => a.UserId == userId).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault(qn => qn.Id == questionnaireId);
```

There is a github issue about this problem: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3474

Comment: This is no longer correct. .ThenInclude().Where() is now included at least on the first level

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have a navigation property of question in your answer because answer should have an question Id . You have this FK already you just need a nav property

Your model class look like this

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string TextAnswer { get; set; }
    // added in model
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

and query like this

```
  var answers = ctx.Answers.Include(q=>q.Question).Where(a =>a.UserId=="1").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have navigation properties filtered on memory:

```
var questionnaire= _context.Questionnaire.FirstOrDefault(qn => qn.Id == questionnaireId);

questionnaire.Answers = _context.Entry(questionnaire)
 .Collection(b => b.Answers )
 .Query()
 .Where(a => a.UserId == userId).ToList();
```