# Include / ThenInclude with where in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to use where in ThenInclude

```
var templatesFields = await _context.Sections
.Include(x => x.Subtitles)
.ThenInclude(r => r.Fields.Where(t=>t.TemplatesFields.TemplateID==TemplateID))
.ThenInclude(r => r.OptionSources)
.ThenInclude(r => r.OptionsSourcesDetails)
.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Pirior to .Net 5 :**

you cannot use where condition inside `Include` or `ThenInclude`. What you can do is:

```
var templatesFields = await _context.Sections
    .Include(x => x.Subtitles)
    .ThenInclude(r => r.Fields)
    .ThenInclude(r => r.OptionSources)
    .ThenInclude(r => r.OptionsSourcesDetails)
    .Where(t=>t.Subtitles.Fields.Any(x => x.TemplatesFields.TemplateID==TemplateID))
    .ToListAsync();
```

**With .Net 5:**

This is possible starting with .Net Core 5.0

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(e => e.Posts.Where(p => p.Title.Contains("Cheese")))
    .ToList();
```

[Filtered Include](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore5.com/whats-new-in-ef-core-5/filtered-included)

Comment: I've formulated my code with this structure though i haven't tried it yet for lacking data, still i 1 up it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still learning this, so test it before assuming I'm right, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't work as intended.

The where clause of Fields is to reduce the field records attached to the subtitles, but in the solution provided, it is just removing any templates that have no Subtiutle.Fields records.

In effect the question asks for "Give me All templates and include field information that matched the condition" where as the answer provided says "Give me all the templates and All the field information where the template has Any field that matches the condition."

Comment: IT is not problem, IT is a feature. Check NEt COre 5 https://www.learnentityframeworkcore5.com/whats-new-in-ef-core-5/filtered-included

Comment: probably this solution won't work for OptionSources and OptionsSourcesDetails if you want to add where clause for its entities. correct me if i'm wrong. What will be the solution in this situation. In EF Core 3.1

Answer (score -2):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42063725):

> Filtering in `Include` or `ThenInclude` is not supported. Create projection by using `Select`:
>
> ```
> questionnaire = _context.Questionnaires
>     .Select(n => new Questionnaire
>     {
>         Id = n.Id,
>         Name = n.Name,
>         Questions = n.Questions.Select(q => new Question
>         {
>            Id = q.Id,
>            Text = q.Text,
>            Answers = q.Where(a => a.UserId == userId).ToList()
>         }).ToList()
>     })
>     .FirstOrDefault(qn => qn.Id == questionnaireId);
> ```