# Using ThenInclude with condition in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
return _companyRepository.GetAll().Where(company => company.Id == Id)
             .Include(company => company.offices.Where(o => o.IsActive))
             .ThenInclude(office => office.People.Where(p => p.IsFired))
             .ThenInclude(person => person.Children)
             .ToList();
```

How can I get all fired people of all active offices using Entity Framework Core?

I'm getting this error:

> Where clause in not valid inside ThenInclude or Include

```
company.offices.Where(o => o.IsActive) 
office.People.Where(p => p.IsFired)
```

I know I can not use `Where` inside `Include`. the question is how to filter data with `Include` clause?

Comment: do not put Where expression into Include.

Comment: why would you do that? you can simply use .Select() actually I cant understand why people use Include methods. Select is pretty easy and clear. if someone explain this to me I  would be appreciated, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

I'd suggest to look around for any of the 3rd party libraries listed there, example :

[EntityFramework.Filters](https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters)

[Query IncludeFilter](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

[How to filter “Include” entities in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641553/5576498)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use any `Include`, in case of you use your data in your query. `Include` is just a way to disable Lazy Loading. `Include` controls whether a navigation property is filled with data or not. `Include` is not made to filter anything.

Your query will also return companies (with people) not people.

```
  return _companyRepository.GetAll().Where(company => company.Id == Id)
         .SelectMany(company => company.offices)
         .Where(o => o.IsActive)
         .SelectMany(office => office.People)
         .Where(p => p.IsFired) 
         .Include(person => person.Children)
         .ToList();
```

This creates a List with persons, including their children.
The last `include` controls says, all the children are loaded with this query. If you remove this `include`, you still can access the children, but than it is load-on-demand or lazy-loading. You will not notice any difference in the functions of your program, but in the communication with your sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

This became possible in EF Core 5.  See [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620036/include-theninclude-with-where-in-ef-core) and the supporting [Microsoft Docs](https://include-theninclude-with-where-in-ef-core).  Here's their example:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(e => e.Posts.Where(p => p.Title.Contains("Cheese")))
    .ToList();
```